# Any way to get Solr highlighting tags embedded without entity encoding?

Tags: xml, xslt, solr, xslt-2.0

When I parameterize Solr to highlight my search term hits, it does so, but encodes the emphasis tags like this...

```
&lt;em&gt;pineapple&lt;/em&gt;
```

How might I eliminate the encoding so the output looks like…

```
<em>pineapple</em>
```

In my context, I am using the highlight tags to transform the output via XSL and encoded tags do not trigger the template.

I'm currently using Solr 4.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

use `disable-output-escaping="yes"`

Assuming your input is:

```
<data>&lt;em&gt;pineapple&lt;/em&gt;</data>
```

**xslt**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="data" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**

```
<em>pineapple</em>
```

Comment: That would work for my output, but I'm asking about Solr's output.

Comment: How are you highlighting your tags? Solr returns valid xml, so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Solr returns highlighting tags as entities (&lt;em&gt;hit&lt;/em&gt;) rather than actual tags (<em>hit</em>).  When I attempt to post process this output with XSLT, no template will match the encoded output.

Comment: Can you use a pipeline approach? Meaning when you get the solr xml result, just normalize the xml, then run you other xslt stylesheet?